# GWT: How can I use Server-Side Permutation Selection?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

At google I/O 2010 talk [Google I/O 2010 - Architecting for performance with GWT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USlUYkBHiHA) There was an optimization with server-side script selection.

In the talk it was pointed out that you can speedup startup time. You can reduce the number of  server round trips from 4 to 2 by doing the initial script selection on the server side instead of on the client side. The talk says that this could be done with Server-Side Permutation Selection.

I could not find any documentation on this topic.

**How do I determine the permutation which should be loaded on the server?**

Comment: Can you summarize the salient points of the Google talk for those of us who don't have an hour to spend watching the video?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit code review has/had such a thing (as far as I see it's gone on master). The interesting parts are in the package "com.google.gwtexpui.linker" and its subpackages:

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/7f53c5696fd2dca0c1f68a0cc9ded8cf43e0948e/gerrit-gwtexpui/src/main/java/com/google/gwtexpui/linker/

Comment: I did not see how this should work. Can you please give me a few more hints?

Comment: The linker in "rebind/ServerPlannedIFrameLinker.java" generates a file "permutations" that contains the mapping of permutations and the properties (browser, locale) that are associated with this permutation. In "server/PermutationSelector.java" you can see how this file is read on the server to get the permutation that should be referenced in the html file (see method select).